# I need clarification on specs for installing a second AC filter and box

Tags: hvac, ducts, air-filter

I'm wanting add a second intake in my house. The filter will be a 12x12 so my question is. How far can I put the new filter from the blower? Is there a code regulation?

Comment: An additional intake (from outside) or an additional return (from inside?)

Comment: sometimes a filter is done at the return grill in the ceiling or wall however far from the air handler that is, or one is installed directly on the intake side of the air handler (i.e. trion airbear).  You can put it wherever, there's no code regulation at least in residential homes.